# How to train SVM using MFCCs calculated?

Tags: matlab, svm, mfcc

I am student of Electrical Engineering and currently i am working on my Final year project at University of Engineering and Technology Peshawar and my FYP is on development of Automatic Speech Recognition System for Pashto language using Machine learning techniques. I am using data set of 234 words of counting from 0 to 25 for training and 78 words from 0 to 25 for testing all sound files are in .wav format and i have calculated MFCCs of all the files individually as <12x34 double> format.

I am working in MATLAB to train SVM classifier for MFCCs i have calculated but i need code on how to  train SVM classifier to predict by comparing MFCCs of test files with MFCCs of train files. This is the code i have used for calculating MFCCs.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.

```
clear all; close all; clc;  


% Define variables
Tw = 25;                % analysis frame duration (ms)
Ts = 10;                % analysis frame shift (ms)
alpha = 0.97;           % preemphasis coefficient
M = 40;                 % number of filterbank channels 
C = 12;                 % number of cepstral coefficients
L = 22;                 % cepstral sine lifter parameter
LF = 0;               % lower frequency limit (Hz)
HF = 4000;              % upper frequency limit (Hz)
T=16000;
% Read speech samples, sampling rate and precision from file
[ Data1, fs, nbits ] = wavread('AA..MN (62).wav');
Data1=imresize(Data1(:,1),[T ,1]);
[ MFCCs1, FBEs, frames ] = ...
                mfcc( Data1, fs, Tw, Ts, alpha, @hamming, [LF HF], M, C, L );

[ Data2, fs, nbits ] = wavread( 'aa.MN (62).wav');
Data2=imresize(Data2(:,1),[T ,1]);
[ MFCCs2, FBEs, frames ] = ...
                mfcc( Data2, fs, Tw, Ts, alpha, @hamming, [LF HF], M, C, L );
```

Comment: What's wrong with the [general documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/audio/examples/speaker-identification-using-pitch-and-mfcc.html?searchHighlight=mfcc&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) and the [function documentation](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/audio/ref/mfcc.html?searchHighlight=mfcc&s_tid=doc_srchtitle) ?

Comment: @obchardon thanks for the concern but i have read these documentations already they lack info regarding implementation of SVM and also they use some online data set which is quite different from my data set.

Comment: Instead of `fitcknn` you can use `fitcecoc` to train a multiclass svm model. But you don't explain where is your problem so it's hard to give you an answer. Your question should be more specific.

Comment: @obchardon sir i have extracted MFCCs individually and want to know the code for SVM classifier to feed these MFCCs as training data and test using test data MFCCs.

Comment: @obchardon and also i donot have Audio Toolbox in my version of MATLAB 2013a.